# Using std::condition_variable to wait in the message sending thread, a deadlock occurred

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a network module, the sending of data is carried out in a separate thread, using a concurrent queue to synchronize data in the main thread.

```
private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable blockNotification_;
    moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue<Envelope> sendQueue_;
    std::promise<bool> senderThreadStopped_;
```

```
void AsyncTransport::RunSender()
{
    while (!drain_)
    {
        SendAllQueuedEnvelope();
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        blockNotification_.wait(lock);
    }

    // Make sure all envelope have been sent.
    SendAllQueuedEnvelope();
    senderThreadStopped_.set_value(true);
    assert(sendQueue_.size_approx() == 0);
}

void AsyncTransport::SendAllQueuedEnvelope()
{
    auto envelope = Envelope::Wrap(nullptr);
    while (sendQueue_.try_dequeue(envelope))
    {
         envelope = syncTransport_->Send(envelope);
    }
}

Envelope AsyncTransport::Send(const Envelope& envelope) const
{
     if (drain_)
     {
          return envelope.With<SentFaildStamp>("The current transport has drained.");
     }

     if (!sendQueue_.try_enqueue(envelope.CloneContent()))
     {
          return envelope.With<SentFaildStamp>("Send queue is full.");
     }

     blockNotification_.notify_all();
     return envelope;
}
```

`RunSender` It runs in a separate thread, and always gets data from the concurrent queue，When all the data in the queue is sent, we wait for the thread to avoid additional cpu overhead until there is new data in the queue.

`Send` method call in main thread.

But I found that I had a deadlock, what did I do wrong?

I expect the sending thread to enter wait after sending data, and wake up again after there is new data in the queue.

Comment: Might be that I am wrong but I don't see the purpose of `unique_lock` in `RunSender` function

Comment: @NutCracker Maybe I did it wrong. It was the first time I used C++ for multi-threaded programming. I read some tutorials and they said that a mutex is needed to block the current thread.

Comment: `unique_lock` is needed to avoid spin-lock (busy-wait) - no CPU cycles will be used when waiting.

Comment: Where exactly are you experiencing deadlock, in the `Send` member function, or when joining the worker thread that's working on `RunSender`?

Comment: @Kaldrr Sometimes `blockNotification_.wait` is not awakened correctly. In other words, when there is data in the queue, RunSender is not awakened.

Comment: and also, not to be nasty or anything, but please read the documentation on condition variables and how to use them. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Send()` method isn't thread-safe. I would use a `std:lock_guard` in a new scope to lock the mutex and ensure it is unlocked before the `notify_all` call like this:

```
Envelope AsyncTransport::Send(const Envelope& envelope) const
{
    {
        const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (drain_)
        {
            return envelope.With<SentFaildStamp>("The current transport has drained.");
        }

        if (!sendQueue_.try_enqueue(envelope.CloneContent()))
        {
            return envelope.With<SentFaildStamp>("Send queue is full.");
        }
    }

    blockNotification_.notify_all();
    return envelope;
}
```

Since the `lock_guard` locks the mutex, you would have to either make the mutex `mutable` to be used in a `const` function or remove the `const` specifier on the function.

---

You should always have a condition with a `wait` to protect against spurious wake-ups. See [CP.42](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rconc-wait). So I would change the `wait` to include a condition like this:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
blockNotification_.wait(lock, [&]() { return drain_ || !sendQueue_.empty(); });
```

Now the `wait` will only wake up once `drain` is true or the `sendQueue` has something in it.

Comment: In fact, I use a concurrent queue for unnecessary locking overhead. Is it possible to implement notifications without using locks in this scenario? (Now it’s actually a lock notification)

Comment: @Candycat The locking is necessary since you are accessing and updating the shared resource, i.e. the queue, in the `Send()` function. Plus the condition variable's wait is checking on the queue. Both things should be atomic. `std::lock_guard` is a lightweight lock compared to `std::unique_lock`.

Comment: @candycat condition variables and mutex locks are linked. You cannot use a condition variable without using a lock, don't even try. If you want a semaphore or an atomic flag, use one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable that is shared between threads and is the condition predicate.

You need to take a lock before reading or writing the predicate. The condition variable wait will unlock before sleeping so the other thread can lock, update the predicate and unlock. You can send the notify before or after unlocking. I prefer after, but meh.

A condition variable *on its own* is useless. It must always go along with a lock protected variable, or set of variables, which must be checked before continuing after waiting.

And of course it then only makes sense to update whatever that variable is before sending a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the deadlock: it may happen that `blockNotification_.notify_all();` happens before `blockNotification_.wait(lock);` and then the latter will wait forever. You need to use `wait_for` that checks if the queue is not-empty so that `block_notification` can exit when new messages are ready to be sent. Be aware of spurious wakeup.